# How do I interpret the line of codes ( \ No newline at end of file) and (+ - core/jquery.once)

Tags: rules

In the Drupal8 zircon/includes/monokai/monokai.min/css patch how do I manually apply the last two lines of code;  ( \ No newline at end of file) and
(+    - core/jquery.once).
Thank you

```
diff --git a/zircon.libraries.yml b/zircon.libraries.yml
index bd6a231..3358a49 100644
--- a/zircon.libraries.yml
+++ b/zircon.libraries.yml
@@ -8,7 +8,7 @@ global-styling:
       includes/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css: {}
       includes/slick/slick/slick.css: {}
       includes/slick/css/style.css: {}
-      includes/monokai/monokai.min/css: {}
+      includes/monokai/monokai.min.css: {}
       includes/flexslider/flexslider.css: {}
       css/html.css: {}
       css/page.css: {}
@@ -38,4 +38,5 @@ global-styling:
     - core/drupal.ajax
     - core/drupal
     - core/drupalSettings
-    - core/jquery.once
\ No newline at end of file
+    - core/jquery.once
```

Answer (score 2):

The message "No newline at end of file" is a warning GIT throws up when there is not a newline as the last line in a file. You can solve this by adding a newline at the very end of the file.

Comment: `You can solve this by adding a newline at the very end of the file.` empty line, right?

Comment: That's correct.

I believe newer versions of GIT do not spit out this warning (at least, I was told that a single time). So upgrading your GIT version could also potentially solve the issue.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, however what am I to do with the patch line of code  (+ - core/jquery.once) that seems contradictory in that I am asked to add  then remove the (+ -  core/jquery.once) line of code?

Comment: It's removing the last line of code (core/jquery.once) which should be a newline, then replacing it with a new line of code (core/jquery.once) followed by a newline. So as to what you are supposed to do, add a newline at the end of the file as I stated. But the question is why are you applying the code in patches manually? Patch files are meant to be applied as a whole, by your system.